# Paths in $\mathbf{Z}^n$ of a certain fixed length

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, lattice-orders

This should be a simple question, but I am unfortunately unable to find a closed-form expression for the following quantity: *the number of integer-valued paths of a certain length $k$ from $(0,\cdots,0)$ to $(P_1,\cdots,P_n)$ on $\mathbf{Z}^n$*.

When $n=1$ this is trivial, but even when $n=2$ I am stuck. Is there a general closed-form expression for the above quantity? Is there an exposition somewhere?

Comment: I take it you don't necessarily have to always move toward the point $P$? That is, from $(0, 0)$ to $(3, 3)$ say, one is allowed to move left or right, up or down?

Comment: @pjs36 Yes, of course. Otherwise it'd probably be easier to find a solution since there can only be certain fixed values of $k$. So for example, to go from $(0,0)$ to $(3,3)$ for a path of length $12$ one could go $(0,0)\to\cdots\to(6,0)\to\cdots\to(6,3)\to\cdots\to(3,3)$.

Comment: OK, just making sure you weren't in the "multinomial coefficients" situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r=|a_1|+|a_2|+\dots +|a_n|-k$ .Clearly if $r<0$ or if $r$ is odd there are no answers, in the second case by chequerboard colouring argument.

Otherwise we obtain the following recursion:
$$f_k(a_1,a_2\dots a_n)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{r/2}f_{k-a_n-2j}(a_1,a_2\dots ,a_{n-1})\binom{k}{a_n+2j}\binom{a_n+2j}{j}$$

Comment: No problem, although there may be something better.